# Android View pager load image one by one on swipe through next page

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-bitmap

I need to show 1000 images in viewpager from DB.The problem is if I fetch all images from DB and try to set those images to adapter,it shows **Bitmap out of memory exception** since heap size gets exceeded. So,I'm trying other way around which is to load images one by one when the user swipes to next page.I Googled a bit,but didn't find any appropriate solution.so any input on this is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here is all that you need : http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html

Load Bitmaps efficiently, LRU cache, etc. etc.

To summarize, you should fetch one bitmap at a time, scale it down using `inSampleSize`and use `LRUCache`. OR, you can use http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-sdk-working-with-picasso--cms-22149 library